# How to password protect a Node server?

Tags: apache, node.js, passwords, socket.io, password-protection

I am very new to both node and Javascript, and am completely lost when it comes to PHP and Apache/nginx. I have an Amazon EC2 instance running my node server, which I am accessing through my browser via http://[my-ip]:[port-number]/.

There are a couple of things I'd like to accomplish -- most importantly, I'd like to require a username/password before the server will accept a client. A secondary objective, but one that I feel may be required in order to password protect the server, is to do away with the port number specification through some kind of proxy forwarding.

I've seen that others have accomplished this by adjusting server configurations and/or other utilities such as haproxy, but the examples were a little over my head and I'd like to understand what I'm doing at each step, because for me this project is more about learning than anything else.

Again, I am VERY inexperienced, so an easy-to-follow, bottom-up suggestion for how I should go about doing this would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's split your question into two:

a) Password protect server

I'm guessing you are talking about the basic HTTP auth. If you are using Express, you can use the Connect middleware in order to achieve that.

Find the example here: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/basicAuth.js 
Read more about it here: http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-basicAuth.html

b) You want a proxy. In production I'd say to choose [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) like you were suggested, but there are also other alternatives written in Node.js like [bouncy](https://github.com/substack/bouncy) or [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) which you can find more easy to understand.